# Dimensionality of the `Y` input for LSTM in Keras

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, lstm

What dimension should the LSTM output be? Currently I'm using `return_sequences=False` and `model.summary()` suggests that the `Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')` layer should have output:

`(None, 1)`

Where `None` is the batch size.

Does it mean that my `y` also has to be 2 dimensional?

Currently I'm using a 1d array of the shape `y.shape = (None,)` which seems to work fine, but I wonder if I should add a new axis to match the dimensions as:
`y = y[:, np.newaxis]`

---

**EDIT:**

Below is my model summary.

Essentially I'm modelling a binary classifier (0 or 1) and I am feeding batches of variable size in both `batch_size` and `time steps`. Hence the dimension of `X.shape = (None, None, no_of_features)`.

As we can see below, the output of the `Dense()` layer is `(None, 1)` where as my `Y` is actually `(Batch_size, )` , a 1d numpy array. Should I add a new axis so that `Y` becomes 2d? E.g. `(batch_size, 1)`?

I tried both, and both of them seem to work. So what's the difference?

```
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
concatenate_8 (Concatenate)     (None, None, 285)    0           numeric_input[0][0]              
                                                                 concatenate_7[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
dropout_3 (Dropout)             (None, None, 285)    0           concatenate_8[0][0]              
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
lstm_4 (LSTM)                   (None, 64)           89600       dropout_3[0][0]                  
__________________________________________________________________________________________________
main_output (Dense)             (None, 1)            65          lstm_4[0][0]                     
==================================================================================================
```

Comment: If you have `return_sequences=False`, the output should be a 2D tensor.If it is `True`, it should be a 3D tensor.What is your `y`?

Comment: My y is a np.array which is 1d by default. But the Keras model runs. It also runs for a 2d array if I add new axis. I'm just not sure which one to use for full training.

Comment: If you mean `y` is the `y_train`, then you can just leave it 1D.

Comment: I see thanks, I'm just passing a `Sequence` generator, which returns `X,y,weights` where X is 3d, y is 1d, w is 1d!

Comment: If somebody is willing to explain what the difference is, feel free to post an answer!

Comment: Please, just add a small example (code) of what you are doing.

Comment: Made an edit, does it make things clearer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both are equivalent and either way works. The reason being is that the  two shapes -- `(None,1)` and `(None,)` -- are compatible and are broadcasted to the same shape automatically. Which is equivalent to you manually adding a new dimension of size 1. [Here](https://learningtensorflow.com/broadcasting/) is some additional reading on broadcasting in tensorflow.